# Getting 401 error while using open weather map api/

Tags: javascript, html, css, api

I am trying to make a weather app but I am getting this error.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmkVM.png)

```
enter code here
```

```
const express =require("express");
const https=require("https");
const bodyParser=require("body-parser");
const app=express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get("/",function(req,res){
res.sendFile(__dirname+"/index.html");
});
app.post("/",function(req,res)
{
  const query=req.body.CityName;
  const api_key="658767b0ae936b022f59a69f44868419"
  const unit="metric";
const url="https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+query+"&appid="+"&units="+unit;
https.get(url,function(response){
  console.log(response.statusCode);
  response.on("data",function(data)
{
const weather_data=  JSON.parse(data);
console.log(weather_data);
const temp=weather_data.main.temp
const icon=weather_data.weather[0].icon
const icon_id=" http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/"+icon+"@2x.png"
res.write("Temp="+temp);
res.write("<img src="+icon_id+">");
res.send();
})
});
})
```

The API key is valid as I have tried using it (https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Trivandrum&appid=658767b0ae936b022f59a69f44868419&units=metric)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to stackoverflow.

You've defined a constant called api_key:

```
const api_key="658767b0ae936b022f59a69f44868419"
```

But you never use it.

You need to change your query to include your api_key as appid:

```
const url="https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+query+"&appid="+api_key+"&units="+unit;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks in your code you missed to add the appid.

Instead of

```js
const url="https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+query+"&appid="+"&units="+unit;
```

add your appid

```js
const myAppId = '1234...';

const url="https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+query+"&appid="+ myAppId +"&units="+unit;
```